# using php to generate html and javascript - quote/doublequotes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This php statement works, but is there a more readable way to express it, in terms of quotation marks.

```
$pCode = $row['SIZIP'];
echo " <a href='#' onClick='jfFn(\"".$pCode."\");return false;' > " . $pCode . "</a>";
```

Comment: Please, if you have opportunity, consider removing the inline event-handlers from the code.

Comment: Sure, in some fantasy land utopia where all layout is in css files and all scripting is in js files and tables are never used for layout you could worry about a tiny inline js snippet.  In the real world, it's just fine.

Comment: @Rob - you have a point... but at some point code readability and maintainability REALLY suffers from issues like this.

Comment: Even if I were somehow *forced* to put the JS in the page I would use a script block at the end to attach an event handler, not an inline onClick. In *my* real world tables aren't used for layout, all CSS is in .css files, and there's zero javascript in the page.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) notation:

```
$pCode = $row['SIZIP'];
echo <<<EOD
<a href='#' onClick='jfFn("$pCode");return false;' > $pCode</a>
EOD;
```

Also, consider using template stuff for what it's meant to be used insetad of using echo to print HTML? You might as well have been using bash otherwise :)

```
<!-- your main document (non-PHP code) is here -->
<?php $pCode = $row['SIZIP'];  ?>
<a href='#' onClick='jfFn("<?php echo '$pCode';?>");return false;' >
<?php echo '$pCode';?></a>
```

or as per Phil Brown's comment

```
<?php $pCode = $row['SIZIP'];  ?>
<a href="#" onclick="jfFn('<?= htmlspecialchars($pCode) ?>'); 
                     return false;"><?= htmlspecialchars($pCode) ?></a>
```

I assume this can be prettified a bit by:

```
<?php $pCode = htmlspecialchars($row['SIZIP']);  ?> 
<a href="#" onclick="jfFn('<?= $pCode ?>'); return false;"><?= $pCode ?></a>
```

Comment: +1 for the 2nd method (templating), except your syntax is a bit off. Enabling short open tags also makes templates look nicer, eg `<a href="#" onclick="jfFn('<?= htmlspecialchars($pCode) ?>'); return false;"><?= htmlspecialchars($pCode) ?></a>`

Comment: re:prettified edit - Only do that if `$pCode` is purely a view-only variable

Comment: @Phil - in the abscence of any indication in the Q that it isn't, i'll assume it is view-only. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/printf)?

```
$pCode = $row['SIZIP'];
printf("<a href='#' onClick='jfFn(\"%s\");return false;'>%s</a>",$pCode);
```

It's a little more readable now!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$pCode = $row['SIZIP'];
echo " <a href='#' onClick='jfFn(\"$pCode\");return false;' >$pCode</a>";
```

or this:

```
echo " <a href='#' onClick='jfFn(\"{$row['SIZIP']}\");return false;' >{$row['SIZIP']}</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{` and `}` when echo'ing with double quotes (only!), like:

```
$pCode = $row['SIZIP'];  
echo "<a href='#' onClick='jfFn(\"{$pCode}\"); return false;'>{$pCode}</a>";
```